# Haskellで以下のエラーが出てしまう

Tags: haskell

「プログラミングHaskell」を勉強していて、9章サンプルコードが実行できず困っています。
https://github.com/macalimlim/programming-in-haskell/blob/master/Chapter9.hs
以下のコードを実行しようととすると、このようなエラーが出てしまいました。
どなたか詳しい方、ご助言頂けるとありがたいです。。

```
Parsing.hs:8:10: error:
    • No instance for (Applicative Parser)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monad Parser’

Parsing.hs:14:10: error:
    • No instance for (GHC.Base.Alternative Parser)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    • In the instance declaration for ‘MonadPlus Parser’
```

コード

```
module Parsing where

import Data.Char
import Control.Monad

newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a, String)])

instance Monad Parser where
    return v = P (\inp -> [(v, inp)])
    p >>= f  = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                          [] -> []
                          [(v, out)] -> parse (f v) out)

instance MonadPlus Parser where
    mzero       = P (\inp -> [])
    p `mplus` q = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                             [] -> parse q inp
                             [(v, out)] -> [(v, out)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse (P p) inp = p inp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHC 7.10 からは仕様が変わって上のようなコードはコンパイルが通らなくなりましたが，対応は簡単です．

---

GHCの7.10からは [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) という名前で知られている変更が入り，

- [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) が [`Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) の親クラスに
- [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) が [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) の親クラスに

なりました．つまり， 何かを `Monad` のインスタンスにしようと思うと，`Applicative` のインスタンスにもしておくことが必要になったということです．以前はこの制約はありませんでしたが，意味的にはこのようにしておいたほうが色々とよいということで，移行がスムーズにできるように気を配りながら導入されることになりました．

従ってコードを修正するには，

- `Parser` を `Applicative` と（そのために，その親クラスである）[`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) に
- さらに `Alternative` に

することが必要になります．具体的な変更点は [GHC 7.10 の移行ガイド](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Migration/7.10#GHCsaysNoinstanceforApplicative...)や [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal#Future-proofing_current_code) に書かれていますが，前者のおすすめに従うと次のようになります．

```
module Parsing where

import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative (Alternative(..))
-- ちょっと面倒ですが

newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a, String)])

instance Functor Parser where
    fmap = liftM
instance Applicative Parser where
    pure v = P (\inp -> [(v, inp)]) -- ここに，Monad の return で書いていたコードを移す
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Parser where
    -- return はデフォルトで Applicative の pure なので，ここには不要
    p >>= f  = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                        [] -> []
                        [(v, out)] -> parse (f v) out)

instance Alternative Parser where
    (<|>) = mplus
    empty = mzero

instance MonadPlus Parser where
    mzero       = P (\inp -> [])
    p `mplus` q = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                            [] -> parse q inp
                            [(v, out)] -> [(v, out)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse (P p) inp = p inp
```

実際には `MonadPlus` も `Alternative` をもとにデフォルト実装があるので，`MonadPlus` で書いてあるコードをまるっと `Alternative` に移したほうがより良いようです．今回は書き換えの負担と相談という感じでしょうか．

`7.10` 以前のバージョンの GHC を用意するのも1つの手ですが（たとえば7.8），個人的にはおまじないを足しつついまお使いの新しいバージョンをそのまま使うほうが良いと思います．

Comment: この変更とその対応についてもうちょっと知りたいときは，Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal については日本語でもそれなりに情報があるので検索で結構いけるとおもいます．

Comment: なるほど、ご丁寧にありがとうございます！

Comment: @mnuma 必須ではないですが，もし解決したなら，横にあるチェックマークをクリックして「承認」して頂けるとシステム上問題が解決したことがわかりやすくなり，あと僕が喜びます（[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか? - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) もご覧ください）．逆にまだ分からないところがあるとか，もっといい回答が欲しいとかがあれば，もちろん遠慮なさらず書いてくださいね．